# Using Scipy.Optimize.Minimize efficiently when compting gradient requires function evaluation

Tags: python, scipy, minimize

so i want to use scipy to minimize a function. In my application i am required to do a function evaluation every time the gradient is required.

I undersand that i can pass a function that will return both, functionvalue and gradient, when i set the arg jac=True. However, sometimes i assume that this procedure will compute gradients when they are not required, e.g. for linesearch, which is very expensive. Is there any way to pass an argument to evaluate the function and an argument to evaluate function and gradient?

EDIT:
i also dont want do compute gradient and functionvalue independently by passing fun and jac since then the fun evaluation inside of jac is often wasted.

Comment: Can you expand on what your optimal use case is? Maybe give an example of how you'd like your code to behave. It seems to me that you can just make two minimize objects, one with jac and one without, but I'm sure that's not the solution as it's too obvious

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. I am using an AD tool to compute the derivative. This framework will always evaluate the derivative at the last function evaluation. Therefore, my jac function includes a call of fun. Currently i pass the fun_and_jac argument with jac = True. I however observe that scipy is doing linesearch which, if im not mistaken, does not require the gradient. nevertheless it still calls fun_and_jac and thus exectues my AD without using the result.

Comment: still not totally sure what you're trying to do, or what linsearch is (do you mean newton's method?) but if you don't want to use AD, then why not write the function using numpy or turn off AD in the lib you're using?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a callable to the `jac` argument and it will be used to compute the gradient, while `fun` will still be called to compute the function value.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however when the optimizer wants to compute func and jac at a point, it will essentially compute fun twice since it is included in grad in my application, 
However if it only needs fun at a point, the jac =True option will unnessecarily compute the gradient there.
I want to avoid both....

Comment: I don't think there's a built-in way to do that. You should look at the source for the particular solver you're using. Some of them always want the function value and gradient at the same time (TNC, L-BFGS-B), some want them individually (SLSQP), and others are more complicated.